# Guidance to Architect Enterprise level application in the latest .NET technologies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

I want to architect an enterprise level application based on the latest .NET 4.0 technologies including:

• ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor

• Entity Framework 4

• Unit testing with mock up framework

I need a sample application showing UI layer, business layer and data access for an enterprise.

Comment: Finding a specific example that includes all the technologies listed - that also provides good guidance is going to be exceedingly difficult.  I would imagine your best strategy (assuming you don't strike it lucky) is to find: (1) Solutions that use the general tool-set (or as close as you can get) and use that for general guidance. (2) Solutions that use each specific tool-set (or many a couple) and use them for specific guidance.

Comment: As a developer we know that it's all down to only one contraint and that is TIME. I need something working and proven which help me to get a quick start by minimum efforts. I might never find what I'm looking for but I'm sure there will be others in the situation like me.

Comment: Absolutely - and if you're going to find the right answer it's likely to be here.  Glad you're expectations are realistic :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Shrinkr](http://shrinkr.codeplex.com/). Hasn't been updated to MVC 3 yet, but probably the best end to end example I've seen out there.

http://shrinkr.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are several at [codeplex](http://codeplex.com/). Start by looking at [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/).

Comment: [The MVC MusicStore](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) uses MVC3 & EF

Comment: NerdDinner is based on MVC 2. MVC Music Store is a using CodeFirst EF. I want to know how people are using EF in the enterprise just like we are very comfortable with WebForm with our own DataAccess layer and BusinessLogic layer seperate. However, The Project Silk is the good one. Anyway, thanks guys.

Comment: @iNain generally they don't Enterprise doesn't stick to cutting edge because it's unstable / risky.

Comment: You're probably right. Basically, I need to see what options are best to develop enterprise MVC. We have been encourage to embrace TDD and I have two options: (a) Go with MVP with WebForm or (b) Get started with MVC 3. I need a sort of the project skeleton/best practices which helps me to implement the pieces of the enterprise jigsaw puzzle quickly.

Comment: MS Sample code doesn't reflect "enterprise level architecture".  Its demo/tutorial code.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't looked at it for a while, but [S#arp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/) is excellent.

Comment: Over engineered or "enterprise?". :-) Complexity upfront is sometimes a good thing if it reduces it over the lifetime of the project.